# Google Apps Marketplace Enable Individual Install

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

The setting "Enable Individual Install" has recently been added in a Google Apps Markeptplace configuration, but I was not able to find its meaning. Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an email from a google representative today with the following:

We’re excited to let you know that you will soon be able to enable anyone within an organization to install your app directly from the Google Apps Marketplace. To prepare for this new feature, you should choose whether to enable or disable individual user installs for your app.

Please follow these instructions to enable individual user installs:

1. Navigate to your Google Developer Console.
2. Select your Google Apps Marketplace project.
3. Click APIs under the APIs & auth section.
4. Click the gear icon next to Google Apps Marketplace SDK.
5. Check Enable Individual Install
6. Click Save changes.

This feature is only available for apps in Google Apps Marketplace that use OAuth 2.0. To learn how to upgrade your OAuth 1.0 app to OAuth 2.0, please see these upgrade instructions. Please also note, only individual users of Google Apps for Business, Google Apps for Education, and Google Apps for Government will be able to install your app.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was announced today in a [blog post](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ch/2014/09/allowing-end-users-to-install-your-app.html). To quote:

> Now, any Google Apps user can install these applications by logging into Google Apps, clicking the app launcher icon , clicking More, and then clicking More from Apps Marketplace.