# public without "enable individual install" checked

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

While configurating the GSuite Marketplace API in the developer console for my app, if I uncheck "Enable individual install" to have the application installed for all users of the domain, my application is not visible anymore by GSuite users in the marketplace (except the one's with admin priviledge for the GSuite domain). 
How can I have my application public again in the marketplace without checking this option ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573887/google-apps-marketplace-enable-individual-install), be noted that this feature is only available for apps in Google Apps Marketplace that use OAuth 2.0. Only individual users of Google Apps for Business, Google Apps for Education, and Google Apps for Government will be able to install your app. Also, from this [blog](http://www.googblogs.com/category/google-apps-developer-blog/page/3/), apps not enabled with individual install will not appear to consumers, nor will they be installable for them.